# ¿Cómo poner leyendas a las líneas de geom_line() en un mismo comando de ggplot?

Tags: r, tidyverse, ggplot

Estaba intentando hacer una grafica que tuviera dos entradas de geom_line() para comparar la diferencia visual entre ambas. El problema es que no se que comando usar para que me aparezca una leyenda que describa qué es la linea roja y qué es la linea negra.
Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
ggplot(taylor_1) +
  geom_line(aes(x=tiempo, y=PIB_rate), color="black") +
  geom_line(aes(x=tiempo, y=taylor_1$`Brecha PIB`), color="red") +
  ggtitle("Filtro HP y ciclo")
```

La grafica que me arroja es esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo que me gustaria obtener son unas etiquetas asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

EJEMPLO:

```
x <- c(2,4,6,8,10)
y <- (6:10)
z <- (1:5)
df <- data.frame(x,y,z)

ggplot(df) +
  geom_line(aes(x=z, y=x), color="black") + 
  geom_line(aes(x=z, y=y), color="red")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la grafica mostrada me gustaria que saliera una leyenda con el nombre de lo que significa la linea "roja" y otra leyenda que tuviera la linea "negra". NO busco segmentar la información categóricamente respecto a otro vector agregando al código así:

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_line(aes(x=z, y=x, color="categoria"))
```

Sino que busco poner labels para cada linea ya establecida.

Comment: ¡Hola! ¿Podrías proporcionar la estructura de tus datos `taylor_1`? Eso facilitaría la ayuda para poder automatizar la creación de la leyenda.

Comment: Hola R18, ya modifique mi pregunta :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo se le deben poner los nombres de las etiquetas en el comando de "color"

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_line(aes(x=z, y=x, color= "X")) + 
  geom_line(aes(x=z, y=y, color="Y")) +
  labs(color = "X_Y")
```

O tambien se pueden guardar todas las variables en una sola columna y usar sus nombres como etiquetas de color

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(c(x, y), names_to = "catogory") %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x = z, y = value, color = catogory))
```

Answer (score 0):

lo recomendable es que utilices la variable Periodo como valor de color.

```
ggplot(taylor_1) +
  geom_line(aes(x=tiempo, y=PIB_rate), color=Periodo) +
  geom_line(aes(x=tiempo, y=taylor_1$`Brecha PIB`), color=Periodo) +
  ggtitle("Filtro HP y ciclo")
```

Te recomiendo colocar los nombres en minuscula o limpiarlos con la funcion `clean_names` del paquete `janitor`, ejemplo:

```
taylor <- taylor_1 |> janitor::clean_names()
```

Los nombres de las variables quedarían:

```
pib_rate   
brecha_pin # Sin las comillas y no tendras que usar el operador $
periodo
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. No conocía la función clean_names, me resultó muy útil. Ya edite mi respuesta para especificar mejor lo que me gustaria hacer, agregando codigo de prueba.